# Using CUDA Thrust in existing C project: Compilation Error

Tags: c++, c, cuda, thrust, nvcc

I'm trying to incorporate the following basic code (`radix_sort_128x.cu`) into an existing `C` project:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>                                                
#include <thrust/copy.h>                                                         
#include <thrust/sort.h>                                                         

#include "cuda.h"                                                                
extern "C" {                                                                     
    #include "radix_sort_128x.h"                                                  
}                                                                                

__host__ __device__ bool operator<(const mm128_t & lhs, const mm128_t & rhs)        
{ return lhs.x < rhs.x; }                                                        

extern "C"                                                                       
void radix_sort_128x_kernel(mm128_t* list, size_t n) {                           
    thrust::device_vector<mm128_t> list_d(list, list + n);                       
    thrust::sort(list_d.begin(), list_d.end());                                     
    thrust::copy(list_d.begin(), list_d.end(), list);                               
}
```

However, when I try to compile this file using NVCC (`nvcc -c -o radix_sort_128x.o radix_sort_128x.cu`), I get the following error:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc: In instantiation of ‘static std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep* std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::_S_create(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc:578:28:   required from ‘static _CharT* std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, const _Alloc&, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _FwdIterator = const char16_t*; _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:5052:20:   required from ‘static _CharT* std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_construct_aux(_InIterator, _InIterator, const _Alloc&, std::__false_type) [with _InIterator = const char16_t*; _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:5073:24:   required from ‘static _CharT* std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_construct(_InIterator, _InIterator, const _Alloc&) [with _InIterator = const char16_t*; _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc:656:134:   required from ‘std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>; std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]’
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:6725:95:   required from here
/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.tcc:1067:1: error: cannot call member function ‘void std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::_M_set_sharable() [with _CharT = char16_t; _Traits = std::char_traits<char16_t>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char16_t>]’ without object __p->_M_set_sharable();
```

It appears that any of my `#include` statements (using the Thrust headers) cause this error, and is probably due to C vs C++ conflicts. Any idea how to fix this? I've tried just compiling the whole project as C++, but that didn't fix anything. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would guess you are trying to use a gcc version which is incompatible with the CUDA toolkit version you have. I say guess because you have not said what version of CUDA you are using.....

Comment: I'm using GCC 8.3.1 and CUDA release 10.1. Should those be compatible? Changing GCC to 4.3.5 also doesn't fix anything

Comment: That should work. Next guess would be something related to mm128_t. Does it contain strings or other c++ standard library types? Those are not supported on the GPU

Comment: No, it's just a `struct` of two `uint64_t`, `x` and `y`. Are those supported on the GPU? They should be, right?

Comment: OK -- third and final guess, it is something included in that include file you haven't described. Taking you at your word gets me this: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/hMuVms and as you can clearly see, it compiles without error using the toolchain you say you are using

Comment: That wasn't it either. I commented out the `radix_sort_128x.h` include (which does include other files, btw) and added the struct definition locally, but I still get the compilation error shown above. Even though my code is now identical to what you showed in GodBolt.

Comment: I'm pretty unfamiliar with RedHat, and usually develop in Ubuntu. Could it have something to do with `devtoolset` changing default libraries/etc on me?

Comment: OK so I will circle back to my original comment, your host toolchain isn't compatible with the CUDA version you are using. I can't help you any more than that sorry

Comment: When I compile the code from godbolt on RHEL7, CUDA 10.1.243, gcc 4.8.5, it compiles cleanly for me.  The last gcc 8 version that was tested with CUDA 10.1.243 is 8.2.1, not 8.3, so its possible there is a difference there.  But if you say that you switched to gcc 4.8.5 and it didn't fix anything, then I'm quite confident your host environment is messed up.  Those claims are not all supportable.  If you switched to gcc 4.8.5, and you are still getting errors of the form `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/...`, then my claim is you did not switch to gcc4.8.5 (correctly).

Comment: Thank you so much, you're both right! Sorry for wasting your time. Although I changed project compilation from gcc8.3.1 to gcc4.3.5, I didn't change the softlink in `/usr/local/cuda/include` to point to the new gcc location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My CUDA version (10.1) was incompatible with the GCC version (8.3.1). I had attempted to downgrade GCC to 4.3.5, but didn't realize the symbolic link in `/usr/local/cuda/include` was pointing CUDA to the `devtoolset-8` GCC version 8.3.1 and my attempt to downgrade had failed.

Comment: I will. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please remember to  accept this answer so it falls of the unanswered question list for the CUDA tag